# Navigator pushes a new page before the async call finishes on button clicked flutter

Tags: firebase, flutter, asynchronous, async-await, navigation

### Description of the problem

So I created an app and I am trying to add some data to firebase when a user signs up. So on my sign up page I have a sign up button which creates the firebase user, add some data to firebase and then switches to homepage.

The problem is that it does not seem to wait for my asynchronous actions to finish before switching to homepage (which creates several problem later but that is not the point). In order to come to this conclusion I made several tests with delayed print functions and it confirms what I just explained.

Note that I also tried to use then instead of async and await but still the same problem and I already searched similar problems but I can't find any solution.

Another precision : all my other problems don't occur when I sign in, so the problem seems to be in the sign up process.

So I was wondering if I didn't make something wrong in the button action function.

### My code

```
RoundedButton(
            buttonAction: () async {
              
                setState(() {
                  showSpinner = true;
                });
                try {
                  final newUserResult =
                      await _auth.createUserWithEmailAndPassword(
                    email: _email,
                    password: _password,
                  );
                  User _user = newUserResult.user;

                  await _user.updateProfile(displayName: _fullName);

                  _user = _auth.currentUser;

                  var test = await _firestore
                      .collection('users')
                      .doc(_user.uid)
                      .collection('assets')
                      .add({
                    'name': 'CASH',
                    'symbol': '\$',
                    'amount': 500.0,
                  });
                  print(test.id);
// This is a test, the message is printed once I am already on my homepage
                  await Future.delayed(const Duration(seconds: 4), () {
                    print('waiting finished');
                  });
Navigator.pushReplacementNamed(context, HomePage.id);
                print('change done');
                } catch (e) {
                  //TODO use a refractored dialog

                  print(e);
                }
                setState(() {
                  showSpinner = false;
                });
                
              
            },
```

### Output

This is the output when I sign up. However I think it is mainly due to the problems I have building the homepage because of the firebase updates that are not finished before switching page.
I am pretty sure of that because when I switch between other pages and this one I don't have any problems building it, but only when I sign up.

```
    flutter: User is signed in!
flutter: Invalid argument(s)

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The following NoSuchMethodError was thrown building AssetCard(dirty):
The method 'toStringAsFixed' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: toStringAsFixed(1)

The relevant error-causing widget was
AssetCard
lib/…/HomeScreens/DashboardScreen.dart:134
When the exception was thrown, this was the stack
#0      Object.noSuchMethod (dart:core-patch/object_patch.dart:51:5)
#1      AssetCard.build
package:crypto_coach/components/AssetCard.dart:35
#2      StatelessElement.build
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4701
#3      ComponentElement.performRebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4627
#4      Element.rebuild
package:flutter/…/widgets/framework.dart:4343
...
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════

════════ Exception caught by widgets library ═══════════════════════════════════
The method 'toDouble' was called on null.
Receiver: null
Tried calling: toDouble()
The relevant error-causing widget was
LayoutBuilder
lib/…/pieChart/PieChartView.dart:21
════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════════
flutter: VWLLRnHddf5uJ3s12KMt
flutter: on a fini d'attendre
flutter: Looking up a deactivated widget's ancestor is unsafe.
At this point the state of the widget's element tree is no longer stable.
To safely refer to a widget's ancestor in its dispose() method, save a reference to the ancestor by calling dependOnInheritedWidgetOfExactType() in the widget's didChangeDependencies() method.
[VERBOSE-2:ui_dart_state.cc(177)] Unhandled Exception: setState() called after dispose(): _SignUpScreenState#8db90(lifecycle state: defunct, not mounted)
This error happens if you call setState() on a State object for a widget that no longer appears in the widget tree (e.g., whose parent widget no longer includes the widget in its build). This error can occur when code calls setState() from a timer or an animation callback.
The preferred solution is to cancel the timer or stop listening to the animation in the dispose() callback. Another solution is to check the "mounted" property of this object before calling setState() to ensure the object is still in the tree.
This error might indicate a memory leak if setState() is being called because another object is retaining a reference to this State object after it has been removed from the tree. To avoid memory leaks, consider breaking the reference to this object during dispose().
#0      State.setState.<anonymous closure> (package:flutter/src/widgets/fra<…>
```

Little precision : the "on a fini d'attendre" message is the "waiting finished" function, I updated it in the post because it is in French but not in my code.

### Asset Card code

```
import 'package:flutter/material.dart';
import 'package:crypto_coach/constants.dart';

class AssetCard extends StatelessWidget {
  AssetCard({this.name, this.symbol, this.amount, this.dollarValue});
  final String name;
  final String symbol;
  final double amount;
  final double dollarValue;

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {
    return SizedBox(
      width: 160,
      child: Card(
        shape: RoundedRectangleBorder(
          borderRadius: BorderRadius.circular(15.0),
        ),
        margin: EdgeInsets.only(left: 8.0, right: 8.0, top: 8.0, bottom: 20.0),
        elevation: 10.0,
        child: Padding(
          padding: EdgeInsets.all(10.0),
          child: Column(
            crossAxisAlignment: CrossAxisAlignment.start,
            children: [
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Text(name,
                    style: (name == 'CASH') ? kCashName : kCurrencyName),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 2,
                child: Text(
                  (((name == 'CASH')
                          ? amount.toStringAsFixed(1)
                          : amount.toStringAsFixed(2)) +
                      ' ' +
                      symbol),
                  style: kCryptoValue,
                ),
              ),
              Expanded(
                flex: 3,
                child: Text(
                  (name != 'CASH')
                      ? ('\$' + dollarValue.toStringAsFixed(1))
                      : '',
                  style: kdollarValue,
                ),
              ),
            ],
          ),
        ),
      ),
    );
  }
}
```

### Solution (update)

Finally the problem was that I had a listener which was doing the navigation thing when it detected a new user signed in, so the data wasn't set yet.

(Excuse me for my poor English, I am French.)

Comment: It looks fine. Please provide the output and exceptions, if any.

Comment: Okay, I updated the post with the output.

Comment: On line 35 of AssetCard.dart, a null is used instead of a double. We would need to see that code to help further.

Comment: It receives a null because I try to retrieve the "assets" from firebase. On sign up I create the first asset but the async call is not finished when I arrive on homepage so it retrieves nothing. However it works fine when I go to another page and I come back to this first one, because the async call is finished.

Comment: And that is in the `HomePage` I assume, to which you are going at the end of this function you pasted. This function looks fine. One possibility is that it may be going to where you have `//TODO use a refractored dialog`. In that case you are printing and ignoring the exception and still going to `Homepage`, without getting the data. This is my best bet given the information you shared.

Comment: I put the navigator switch inside the try block but still the same, moreover I don't have any error printed so I am not in catch block.

Comment: The next possibility is that sign up does not do sign in. `_user = _auth.currentUser;` probably returns null. But then `_user.uid` would throw and you could not go to the other page. Best one can do is set breakpoints and debug line by line. I can confidently say that your theory of things happening too slow is wrong. Execution simply can't skip `await` and navigate away in the lines below. Something else is probably also doing navigating. Breakpoints and debugging is the way ot figure it out.

Comment: I can try do add sign in but I think I an pretty sure it already does because I have a user listener which tells me I am signed in and I can access user data in the other parts of the app. (I added the asset card code in the post if it can be useful.

Comment: OH I found thank you very much for your help! The problem was that my listener (for user signed in) was doing the navigation directly when the user was created so the data wasn't set yet! By the way, if you have advices to improve my posts, don't hesitate I am new here and maybe I am not doing it correctly.

Comment: Makes perfect sense. I just wrote an answer with this, if you want to accept :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This code looks fine.

Based on our discussion in comments, it turns out your signed in listener was doing the navigation rather than this code.